# Extending L.Control.Layers hover fails

Tags: javascript, leaflet

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgvogpq6/3/)

I want to extend `L.Control.Layers` because I want to be able to change the icon via options. Here is the element so far:

```
var layers = L.Control.Layers.extend({

    options: {
        position: 'topright',
        icon: 'podcast',
    },

    initialize: function (options) {
        L.setOptions(this, options);
        L.Control.Layers.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
    },

    onAdd: function (map) {
        var container = L.Control.Layers.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);
        container.classList.add('st-control-layers');
        container.childNodes[0].innerHTML = '<center><span style="margin-top:4px;" class="fa fa-2x fa-' +
                                            this.options.icon + '"></span></center>';
        return container;
    },
});
```

Event without modifying the `<a>` childNode, when hovering over the control it collapses but the list of layers is not displayed:

```
var stLayerControl = layers(null, {'one': L.layerGroup()}).addTo(this);  // 'this' is a map
```

When inspecting elements, I can see that the `<form>` exists and has the 3 divs a normal `Control.Layers` has, however, the last div (with class `leaflet-control-layers-overlays`) which is the one that should have the array of checkboxes has no children nodes.

Maybe I need to call something else on the parent in my `onAdd()` method but I am not sure what it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not passing the layers received to the parent, that's why the list was empty. Here is the working version of the extended control:

```
var layers = L.Control.Layers.extend({

    options: {
        position: 'topright',
        icon: 'podcast',
    },

    initialize: function (baseLayers, overlays, options) {
        L.setOptions(this, options);
        L.Control.Layers.prototype.initialize.call(this, baseLayers, overlays, options);
    },

    onAdd: function (map) {
        var container = L.Control.Layers.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);
        container.classList.add('st-control-layers');
        container.childNodes[0].innerHTML = '<center>' +
                                            '<span style="margin-top:4px;" class="fa fa-2x fa-' +
                                            this.options.icon + '"></span>' +
                                            '</center>';
        return container;
    },
});

module.exports = {
    Layers: layers,
    layers: function(baseLayers, overlays, options) {
        return new layers(baseLayers, overlays, options);
    },
};
```